# Accessing CustomValidator isValid Property - Visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am currently using FormView to display a form using my database. I have added a customvalidator within the formview and wish to use c# to validate user entry.

As the textbox is in the form view i have used to following code to access the input:

```
String phoneNum = (FormView1.FindControl("NumberTextBox") as TextBox).Text;
```

And the following to access the custom validator:

```
Control CustomValidator1 = FormView1.FindControl("CustomValidator1");
```

when i use  customValidator1.isValid, i get "does not contain a defination isValid"

I am wondering if there is a way to use the isValid property, and have i accessed the customvalidator correctly?

Thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

Try casting CustomValidator1 to it's type not to Control.

Comment: No good. "the type or namespace name'customvalidator1' could not be found". thanks anyway :)